# Can I specify a dll from which to use New-Object in Powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a scenario where by I need to `New-Object` a type but there are multiple types with the same name and namespace. I can't find how `New-Object` decides which dll to create the type from when it exists in multiple places. Is it possible to specify? Ideally I'd like to pass the dll name to the `New-Object` but there doesn't appear to be an option for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the full [assembly-qualified type name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-determine-assembly-fully-qualified-name):

```
New-Object -TypeName 'MyType, AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdef0123456789'
```

This works with type literals as well:

```
[MyType,AssemblyName,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=abcdef0123456789]::new()
```

---

You can easily obtain the fully qualified name of an assembly from disk with `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName()`:

```
# Load the assembly
$AssemblyPath = '.\MyAssembly.dll'
Add-Type -Path $AssemblyPath

# Fetch the assembly's name
$AssemblyName = [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName((Resolve-Path $AssemblyPath).Path)

# Construct full type name
$TypeName = 'MyType'
$AssemblyQualifiedTypeName = $TypeName,$AssemblyName -join ', '

# Instantiate and object of this type
$MyObject = New-Object -TypeName $TypeName
#or
$MyObject = ($TypeName -as [Type])::new()
```

Comment: You can get the assembly's qualified type name (aka, assembly strong name, or assembly full name) directly with `[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($Path).FullName`.  If the type is already loaded, you can call `([TypeName]).Assembly` to get the assembly or `([TypeName]).Assembly.FullName` or `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssembly([TypeName]).FullName` to get the qualified type name from the type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use `LoadFrom`:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(dllPath)
```

Then PS should first look into it when using `New-Object FullyQualifiedType`  .

EDIT :

Alternatively, it seems there is an option to specify an DLL assembly with `Add-Type` :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-5.1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "yourAssembly"
```

Then, the type will be available in the current PowerShell session.